# Trying to Update UI of Appcompact Activity via ImageLoader Class(Using a thread)

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, universal-image-loader

ImageLoader.Class

```
 {
   BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
   Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
   a.runOnUiThread(bd);
 }
   class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}

    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
            Log.d("A","Returning");
            return;
        }
            if(bitmap!=null) {
                Log.d("A","Setting Image");
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
                else {
                Log.d("A","Setting ICON");
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
                Log.d("A","we are in ui thread");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
   public class Main_Menu_Activity  extends AppCompatActivity
   implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    }
```

But WHEN I REPLACE "EXTENDS APPCOMPACTACTIVTY" BY "EXTENDS ACTIVITY" in MainActivity then THREAD -"BitmapDisplayer" EXECUTES FINE.

Comment: you can use UIL library with their callback.

Comment: @SanketKachhela thanks for reply but can you help out in Appcompact thing?

Comment: callback will work same for AppCompact things

Comment: @SanketKachhela there is no getContext() method on AppCompatActivity then how to gets its Context

Comment: this keyword iteself will be your activity context

Comment: @SanketKachhela how i am gonna use this keyword in                     Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
   a.runOnUiThread(bd);